# Checkboxes for attribute list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am new to ASP.NET and web programming in global.

I'm trying to make web application for job applications. I've managed to save applicant name, mail etc. but now I'm having troubles with checkboxes. Every applicant should have Skills property which contains list of applicants skills (like Java, JavaScript etc.).

In my form there should be checkbox for every skill but I can't achieve that.

I have this so far:

My model:

```
public class Applicant
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FName { get; set; }

    public string LName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Letter { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(Sex))]
    public Sex Gender { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(Pos))]
    public Pos Position { get; set; }     

    public enum Sex
    {
        [Display(Name = "Male")]       Male = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Female")]      Female = 2
    }

    public enum Pos
    {
        [Display(Name = "Front-end")]               Frontend = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Back-end")]                Backend = 2,
        [Display(Name = "Tester")]                  Tester = 3,
        [Display(Name = "System administrator")]    SysAdmin = 4,
        [Display(Name = "Project manager")]         ProjMan = 5,
        [Display(Name = "Database specialist")]     Database = 6,
    }

    [Display(Name = "Candidate skills: ")]
    public List<Skills> SkillList { get; set; }  

    public static List<Skills> getSkills()
    {
        List<Skills> skills = new List<Skills>()
        {
            new Skills() { ID = 1, skillName = "Java", isChecked = false },
            new Skills() { ID = 2, skillName = "JavaScript", isChecked = false },
            new Skills() { ID = 3, skillName = "PHP", isChecked = false },
        };
        return skills;
    }
}

public class Skills
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string skillName { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }        
}
```

In controller I get error

> " Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List jobAppForm.Models.Skills ' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List jobAppForm.Models.Applicant ' "

My controller:

```
    // GET
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<Applicant> model = new List<Applicant>();
        model = Applicant.getSkills();

        return View(model);
    }
```

So I have Create view which contains textboxes for FName, LName.... and dropdownlist for Gender and Position.

What I can't figure out is how to display checkboxes for every skill and save data to database.

Comment: First of all your Applicant.GetSkills() returns a List of Skills but you are trying to assign it to a List of Applicant in your Controller.

Comment: `model = new Applicant(); model.SkillList = Applicant.getSkills(); return View(model);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Skill class contains a name and a boolean property, and assuming you are using Razor for your view, you create a list of checkbox form fields all with a common "name" property but each one includes an index such as name="myname[0]".  When you post the form your controller gets an array of values for "myname" you iterate through.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SkillList.Count(); i++)
{
    string checkedValue = "false";
    @if (Model.SkillList[i])
    {
        checkedValue = "checked";
    }
    @Html.CheckBox("myname[" + i.ToString() + "]", new { @checked = checkedValue })
}
```

Note: when you process the posted values an unchecked box value will be "false" and a checked box will be "true, false" so be careful to interpret the value as myname[i] != "false".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    @for(int i = 0;i < Model.SkillList.Count;i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SkillList[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SkillList[i].skillName)
}
```